# If I want something to consistently be happening while the rest of my program is still running in Python, what do I do?

Tags: python

If i want to make an interest class, where I use a time function to continuously add interest while the rest of the program runs, how would I carry that out?

Comment: What does the rest of the program do? Are there other ongoing processes? Please specify.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use threading:

```
import threading

def interest():
    while True:
        print('interest is running')

d = threading.Thread(target=interest)
d.setDaemon(True)
d.start()

print('Your main job is here')
```

Comment: [" In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.setDaemon)